# Why is it throwing an error from the node_modules folder?

Tags: angular

So, I am rather new to Angular, and I am facing errors while running an app. More interesting is the fact that the exact same project runs fine on my Ubuntu machine, but for some reason, when I copy-pasted the entire folder (minus the `node_modules` folder, I did an `npm install` later) its throwing an error on my Windows. Errors are as below:

```
Error: ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createUniqueName' of undefined
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:69:58)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75069:54)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75079:44)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75069:54)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75079:44)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75133:59)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)

Error: ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createUniqueName' of undefined
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:69:58)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75069:54)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75079:44)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75069:54)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75079:44)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:74798:23)
    at Object.visitEachChild (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75133:59)
    at visitNode (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\transformation.js:76:23)

Error: ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getResourceDependencies is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at getDependencies (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:312:56)
    at path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:453:20
    at analyzingFileEmitter (path-to-my-folder\new-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:358:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Can someone please help me troubleshoot the reason behind these errors?

Comment: Try a couple of things: 1. Compare the versions of Node.js (and see if there's a difference there). 2. Try deleting the package-lock.json file, and running npm install again.

Comment: @Anders Yes, the versions of node.js are different. On my Ubuntu, I have v10.19.0, whereas on my Windows, I have v12.20.1. I deleted the package-lock.json file and reinstalled the node_modules folder, but the error still persists. I have no idea how can I fix it. Looks like something insignificant is wrong, but how would a beginner know, and no one has responded so far.